# How to resolve Google Service Account Team Drive creation error of insufficientFilePermissions?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am attempting to create a Google Team Drive using my Service Account but am receiving a insufficientFilePermissions error.  Does anyone know how to create a Google Team Drive using a Service Account or can identify what I am doing wrong here?

For ease of use, I've created a github project which contains the files presented here.  https://gitlab.com/eghm-lab/stackoverflow-google-service-account-test-drive-creation

I've provided the error, Java code for SOTeamDriveCreate, and a pom.xml below.  After placing SOTeamDriveCreate.java into src/main/java.  One should copy their Service Account credential client_secrets.json file to  the same directory as the pom file.  Then execute:

```
mvn clean compile ; mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=SOTeamDriveCreate
```

The insufficientFilePermissions error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
    "code" : 403,
    "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.",
        "reason" : "insufficientFilePermissions"
    } ],
    "message" : "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at SOTeamDriveCreate.createTeamDrive(SOTeamDriveCreate.java:110)
    at SOTeamDriveCreate.main(SOTeamDriveCreate.java:103)
    ... 6 more
```

SOTeamDriveCreate.java:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.TeamDrive;


public class SOTeamDriveCreate {

    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
            "Drive API Java Quickstart";


    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
            System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/drive-java-quickstart");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
            JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    private static Drive service = null;

    protected static String FILE_FIELDS = "id, name, createdTime, mimeType, trashed, permissions, parents, teamDrive";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);

    private String authFile;

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public SOTeamDriveCreate(String authFile) {
        this.authFile = authFile;
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
                .fromStream(new FileInputStream(authFile))
                .createScoped(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized Drive client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
        if (service == null) {
            Credential credential = authorize();
            service = new Drive.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                            .build();
        }
        return service;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SOTeamDriveCreate createTeamDrive = new SOTeamDriveCreate("client_secrets.json");
        createTeamDrive.createTeamDrive();
    }

    public void createTeamDrive() throws Exception {
        TeamDrive teamDriveMetadata = new TeamDrive();
        teamDriveMetadata.setName("Team Drive created with Service Account");
        String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        TeamDrive teamDrive = getDriveService().teamdrives().create(requestId, teamDriveMetadata).setFields(FILE_FIELDS).execute();
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>so-team-drive-create</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SOTeamDriveCreate</name>
    <description>Google Service Account Team Drive creation</description>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.2.1</maven>
    </prerequisites>
    <properties>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>2.4</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <google.http-client.version>1.23.0</google.http-client.version>
        <google.oauth-client.version>1.23.0</google.oauth-client.version>
        <google.api-client.version>1.23.0</google.api-client.version>
        <google-api-services.version>v3-rev119-1.23.0</google-api-services.version>
        <google-api-services-storage.version>v1-rev132-1.23.0</google-api-services-storage.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Google Drive API. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>${google.api-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${google.oauth-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
            <version>${google-api-services-storage.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>${google.http-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
            <version>${google-api-services.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-assembly</artifactId>
            <version>${google.api-client.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${project.name}</warName>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo>Here are some common goals for this project:</echo>
                                <echo>$ mvn clean compile</echo>
                                <echo>$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=SOTeamDriveCreate</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                    <mainClass>${exec.mainClass}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question so I'll put this as a comment. But, I've wasted about 10 hours on this same problem. For my purposes, I wanted the service account to create the team drive out of convenience. But, it turns out you can create the team drive with a personal account and just invite the service account email. I just checked the box to indicate it shouldn't notify the user. It will warn you the user isn't in the organization (which is fine). But, it worked. You can list the team drive from the service account to then access it by id.

Comment: Thanks, stuckj.  Convenience is what we are looking for as well.  I needed to create 60 Team Drives (will be even more next year) so I created them with a command line tool under a personal account and added the service accounts.  Hoping for a more integrated solution next year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A teammate has solved our problem.

- First, on the Enterprise Admin console we needed to setup our client has having domain wide access.
- Then we used the createCredentialForServiceAccountImpersonateUser from https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.html, which uses the P12File to create the GoogleCredential.  Initially we attempted to use the json file, which worked for everything, EXCEPT creating a new Team Drive, only the P12File version allows for us to create a new Team Drive.