# Creating a shared drive with a service account

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Is it possible to create a [shared drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-shareddrives) with a service account ?.

Since there is no UI for service account to create file/folders i need some way /APIs support to create shared drives.

I can create children (files and folders) under a service account but not sure how to create a shared drive with a service account.

Best Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 1):

> Since there is no UI for service account to create file/folders i need some way /APIs support to create shared drives.

Service accounts are used for accessing Google drive via the google drive api. The [File.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) method would allow you to create a folder and files if you like.

If you create them from the service account they will be created on the service accounts Google drive account.

You can set the parents directory as well when creating it and this will allow you to create it in another directory for example one on your presonal drive account.

I cant say that I have tried but the [drives create method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/create) will let you create a shared drive. It should work just fine from a service account.

Comment: thanks for the reply...drives create API looks promising...is there any java API for that ?...i can see a team drives object in the API...not sure if this is the one

Comment: I tried to create team drives through the api but getting permission denied exception...i think we cannot create shared drive from a service account...this has been discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595511/how-to-resolve-google-service-account-team-drive-creation-error-of-insufficient